# Typo3 ajax call "No Template was found"

Tags: ajax, typo3

I want to make an ajax call to an Action of my Controller. The problem is that I get the error 
*"Sorry, the requested view was not found. No template was found. View could not be resolved for action xy in class xy"* 
Thats my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<f:uri.action action="xy" controller="XY"/>',
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
```

Thats the Action-method of my controller:

```
public function xyAction(){

    if ($this->request->hasArgument("import") && $_FILES["import"]['error'] == 0) {

        $file = $this->request->getArgument("import");
        $ext = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if ($ext != "csv") {
            $this->addFlashMessage('Falsche Dateiendung, es sind nur CSV-Dateien gültig.', '', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::ERROR);
        }
       $participantsArray = $this->parseCSV($file["tmp_name"]);

        return json_encode($participantsArray);

    }else {
        $this->addFlashMessage('Keine Datei ausgewählt', '', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::ERROR);
    }
}
```

The return value of the method *parseCSV($file)* is an array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Helpful comments: 1) controller arguments absolutely should be declared as such. Reading them raw from the request is bad practice. This has many implications, among other things how you would go about building a link to the action and how it behaves with cache controls. 2) Adding flashmessages won't also render those, unless that is done in your template. Since you use XHR it most likely means you're spooling messages, never displaying them. Reloading the page would then spam them all to the user. My recommendation: return messages in the response and mark it as a warning or error response.

Comment: More helpful comments: 3) if this chunk of template code is in a Fluid template (it looks that way) then you may have problems with parsing detecting your JS as Fluid and, just for example, causing a function body to be empty so you don't see the output. 4) Be aware that controller name is UpperCamelCase - you probably do respect this, but the problem is that case errors in class names may not be detected on case-insensitive filesystems (such as default mac-os).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you for some reason don't wish to use the JsonView provided by TYPO3, you will need:

- The template, even if empty, in the expected location. If this does not exist then Extbase will fail even before your controller is loaded.
- Manually creating the response content, for example by `return json_encode($var)` from your controller action.

The logic is: if the method returns NULL then the view will be rendered. If it returns anything else (implied: a non-empty string) then that will be used as response and the view will not be rendered. In essence: not returning anything from the method implies `return $this->view->render();` gets called from the parent controller class.

Since the controller dispatcher can't know in advance that you do not want the View to be rendered, it will fail if it can't resolve the template.

This is also the hint to let you know how you could work around this. Changing the View class to one you created or one that doesn't care if a template file exists, is another way to solve this. There are several ways of doing that but the most common is to set `protected $defaultViewObjectName` in your controller to the class name of your custom View which then doesn't fail if a template is not found.

Regarding headers, you may need to change response content type as well. How you do this would depend on your exact implementation - it might make sense to do that with TypoScript instead of setting it in $this->response.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!
I noticed that my if-condition was wrong and it goes into the else branch without my knowledge.

Comment: Pay special attention to the note about controller arguments that should be declared as arguments on your controller action, as they may have helped add to the confusion about which arguments are actually provided. It is strongly discouraged to access request arguments directly this way, in particular it is discouraged to transfer them as global arguments that are not scoped to your plugin (using proper arguments would automatically avoid that).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try

```
echo json_encode($participantsArray);
die();
```

instead of `return json_encode($participantsArray);`

Answer (score 0):

This happened because of `xy.html` template not found on your extension Template folder. So, You need to do something like below.

You need to add `die()` function after `return json_encode()` line.

Other wise you need to create blank template file for this action like `xy.html`

Comment: The die()-method is not reachable after a return.
I want to avoid creating a new template. It should just return to the ajax calling template.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not solve the real problem, which is that the View is asked to resolve a template file even before the controller action gets called. Failure to resolve that file causes the error - meaning nothing you can do from within the controller action will affect it. The hint to create the blank template file is the right one, but I've also given a few more possible (and imho better) solutions in my answer below.